# How can I schedule Ruby script execution in background?

Tags: ruby, cron

I'm trying to run a script every minute with "SINC is not CRON". I've used the following crontab line

```
* * * * * ruby -X D:/xampp/htdocs/maker ./do.rb
```

and now every minute I get a new cmd window. How can I force Ruby or SINC to invoke these as background processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this link](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/Ruby_and_Microsoft_Windows_Running_Ruby_Under_Windows.html):

> "In these cases, you'll want to use
>   `rubyw.exe`. It is the same as `ruby.exe`
>   except that it does not provide
>   standard in, standard out, or standard
>   error, and does not launch a DOS shell
>   when run."

I'm not familiar with SINC, but something like this should work:

```
* * * * * rubyw -X D:/xampp/htdocs/maker ./do.rb
```

or

```
* * * * * rubyw.exe -X D:/xampp/htdocs/maker ./do.rb
```

FWIW this is similar to Python where you would use `pythonw.exe`.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work, a little odd though - can't find it in the process list